# Overlay of ROI's in ImageJ using Holojprocessor

Tags: java, image, imagej

I'm trying to display Regions of interest(Roi's) over an image, 
Currently I have a holojprocessor (which is part of the HoloJ plugin)  which contains the image, and can show it.

However I can only add Roi's to ImageProcessors, As you can see i've tried various methods of adding overlays to an imageProcessor and then converting it to a HolojProcessor, but i can't get it to work.

Does anyone know how to either add an overlay to a holoJprocessor or, 
Display an ImageProcessor.

Sorry for the poor explanation.

```
HoloJProcessor recon = new HoloJProcessor(hologram);
ImagePlus amplitude = recon.makeAmplitudeImage("Amplitude");
ImageProcessor amplitudeProcessor = amplitude.getProcessor();
MaximumFinder m = new MaximumFinder();

amplitudeProcessor.invert();
ByteProcessor points = m.findMaxima(amplitudeProcessor,tolerance,0,false);
Image pointsImage = points.createImage();
ImagePlus x = new ImagePlus("points", pointsImage);

Roi r = new Roi(512,512,50,50);
    x.setRoi(r);
Roi roi = x.getRoi();

ImageProcessor Mask = x.getProcessor();
    Overlay O = new Overlay(roi);
    Mask.drawOverlay(O);
    Mask.drawRoi(roi);
    Mask.draw(roi);
    Mask.drawDot(512,512);
    Mask.drawPixel(512,512);

    HoloJProcessor holoMask = new HoloJProcessor(Mask);

   holoMask.show("test");
```

Comment: Hi @Andrew. Why do you need to add the ROI to the HoloJProcessor? I had a quick look on the constructors https://github.com/brianm85/4th-year-college-project/blob/master/HoloJProcessor.java and as far as I can see the HoloJProcessor does nothing with the ROI overlay of the ImageProcessor, nor does it keep a reference to the input. So even though your approach sees conceptually sound, the code in the github repo would not suggest the behaviour you desire.

Comment: Also even though the name would suggest it, HoloJProcessor does not extend ImageProcessor.

Comment: Hi @felixthecat, I'm building a lensless microscope and recording the diffraction pattern of cells, In reconstructing the image of the cells it requires an iterative algorithm, It takes a while to run.

So i'm trying to add a preview that will highlight all the points in the cells(with the current parameters), like when you use 'maximum finder' with ' point selection. 

Using an imageProcessor I can do this and get the location of all the points but i want to then add a marker on the image to show where they are. And i thought Roi's were the way to go.

Comment: Did you already see this http://forum.imagej.net/t/overlay-over-imageplus/6603/3?

Comment: You are my hero ! No i did not and that's exactly what I was looking for. 
Thank you!
Post it as an answer so i can accept!